# Sprites inside css with aspnet image framework

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, sprite

Hi im using the sprite framework http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50140

I have it working so that i can do things like:

```
@Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageSprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/icons/calendar.png")
```

but how can i use the images within css files? 
eg

```
#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(/App_Sprites/images/img01.gif) repeat-y left top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image you are referencing in the CSS file exists, then it should work. The CSS path is relative to the CSS file. O you have the path correct? You can check with firebug.

Comment: it works, but i want it to reference the sprite image created by the framework, not the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

This will require you to create CSS file on the fly, at runtime and fix up the paths in your classes and IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the image framework is that it generates the CSS files dynamically. So let's suppose that you have placed your images inside the `~/App_Sprites` folder: img1.png, img2.png, img3.png. Now you simply register the HTTP module in your web.config:

```
<httpModules>
  <add type="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule"
       name="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule" />
</httpModules>
```

and then inside the head section of your page you include the dynamically generated CSS:

```
@ImageSprite.ImportStylesheet("~/App_Sprites/")
```

which will render the following:

```
<link href="App_Sprites/highCompat.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now all that is left is to use the rules contained inside this CSS:

```
<div class="img1-png"></div>
```

Or if you wanted to directly include the image inside your markup:

```
@ImageSprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/img1.png")
```

So the idea is that you use directly the dynamic CSS generated by the framework, you cannot use those rules in your CSS files.

Also make sure you read the [documentation](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50140#DownloadId=140571) for the different modes and the `settings.xml` file which allows you to customize those modes.